# A simple concept question about charaterization of closeness of a space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For first countable topological space  X we know if $x\in \bar{A} \iff \text{exist}\ x_n\to x$  with $x_n\in A$

Hence if $A$ is closed ,$x\in A $ there must exist a sequence converge to it.

My question is does the following statement holds?:

> if for any $x\in A$ exist $x_n\to x$ with $x_n\in A$ then $A$ is
> closed?

It seems not,since closed iff contains **all** the limit point,there may exist some sequence $y_n\to y\notin A$. correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The sequence "for any $x \in A$, exists $x_n \rightarrow x$ with $x_n \in A$" is always true, since you can consider the constant sequence $x_n = x$.

Comment: Thanks (it seems to be a trivial question)

Comment: You are welcome (but thinking about trivial questions is very good when you try to grasp new notions ;))

Comment: "if A is closed ,x∈A there must exist a sequence converge to it " this statement is also not depends on any condition correct,just take constant sequence.  The question then is How to interpret that sequence in first countable space charaterize close set?

Comment: In the characterization, $x$ does not belong to $A$ but to $\overline{A}$. So you cannot always consider the constant sequence.

Comment: Thanks, there is another not very clear question,I forget there is where that sequence behaviour was used to determine the topology?I don't understand why $x\in \bar{A} \iff \text{exist}\ x_n\to x$ is used to determine topology

Comment: What do you mean, "to determinate the topology" ?

Comment: That is for space $X$ equipped with two different  first countable topology $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ if any convergence sequence $x_n\to x$(converge to the same limit) in both topology,then $\tau_1 = \tau_2$ is my statement correct?